# I have a British passport but my child who is 2 was born in South Africa. What type of visa can I get for my daughter to live in the UK?

Tags: passport

I have a British passport but my daughter who is 2 was born in South Africa. I am coming back to live in the UK and want to bring my daughter with me. How do I do this? What type of visa can I apply for once she is here?

Answer (score 5):

The answer depends on the basis of your British citizenship.  If you are a British citizen "otherwise than by descent" then your daughter is also a British citizen, and you should apply for a UK passport for her.

You are a British citizen otherwise than by descent if you were born in the UK or an overseas territory, if you were naturalized as a British citizen, or if you were born outside the UK and territories while your parent was abroad in "crown or similar service."  Details are available at [Children born outside the UK: British citizenship](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/children-born-outside-the-uk-british-citizenship).

If you are a British citizen by descent, then your child is not a British citizen, but may be able to register as one, depending on your circumstances.  For example, if you lived in the UK for a period of three years with no more than 270 days absence during that three-year period, and your father or mother was British, then your daughter qualifies for registration.  This costs £1012.  Details are available at [Apply for citizenship if you have a British parent; You were born on or after 1 July 2006](https://www.gov.uk/apply-citizenship-british-parent/born-on-or-after-1-july-2006).

If your child is not eligible to register as a British citizen, depending on the circumstances of your child's father, she may be able to apply for indefinite leave to remain, which costs £2389 or £2999, depending on whether you apply in person.  Details are available at [Find out if you can apply to settle in the UK](https://www.gov.uk/settle-in-the-uk/y).

As you can see, this is a terribly complex matter, so if you were not born or naturalized in the UK, you may want to talk to an immigration lawyer.